# Laravel Routes Stopped working after SSL Installation

Tags: apache, laravel, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, laravel-5.3

I installed SSL certificate and redirected all routes to https in .htaccess. So far so good.

However, now none of my routes are working. Homepage works but none of the routes work. I get the error 
"The requested URL /deals-coupons/bestbuy.com was not found on this server."
If I visit the same route from http, I am able to access the route.

I added the following code to AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
 if (!\App::environment('local')) {
      \URL::forceSchema('https');
 }
}
```

However, this is also not working. Can someone please help on what I can do to make sure routes work with https.

I am using Laravel 5.3

This is what I have in my httpd.conf (I am using Amazon EC2) file

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ServerName www.ismartsave.com

SSLEngine On

SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl-certs/f8c359c6384f763b.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl-certs/<site>.key

</VirtualHost>



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName ismartsave.com


ServerAlias www.<site>.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How isn't it working? Are you getting an error? Can you give an example? Can you also show what you put in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: @RossWilson: Added details to the original question

Comment: You shouldn't be putting `VirtualHost` inside `.htaccess`

Comment: @RossWilson: misquoted. the code is in httpd.conf file

Comment: when you install the certificates you don't need to mess with routing, that should work as it worked before...